# How can I show that this function is injective, surjective or bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this function $f(n) = \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil $ and I want to proof if it is injective surjective or bijective. Maybe I don't know how to do it because I don't know how to define this function.

Comment: What is a codomain of this function?

Comment: But you have just defined it! Did you compute $f(1)$ and $f(2)$?

Comment: Its always an integer, if it isn't inside its the next largest one of that.

Comment: Take look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444281/how-to-prove-fn-lceil-fracn2-rceil-is-one-to-one-and-onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(1) = \lceil \frac{1}{2} \rceil = 1$

$f(2) = \lceil \frac{2}{2} \rceil = 1$

So $f(1)=f(2)$, and therefore $f$ is not injective.

---

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that $f(2n) = \lceil \frac{2n}{2} \rceil = n$, then $f$ is surjective.

(I suppose that the domain and codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$)

---

How $f$ is not injective, then $f$ is not bijective.

Comment: I forgot to put the domain of the function, but they are the same integers.

Answer (score 2):

$\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.

It's probably most helpful to draw a picture (taken from Wikipedia):

[image]

Now, you should ask yourself:

- Can you find distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\lceil a \rceil = \lceil b \rceil$? If so, the function is not injective.
- Can you find a number $y$ such that for all $x$, $\lceil x \rceil \neq y$? If so, the function is not surjective (assuming the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$).